# Mocking mongoose save() error inside a route

Tags: javascript, mongoose, sinon

After trying all manner of methods to test a route's mongoose `save()` throwing, I was not really sure how it should be done. I'm aiming for 100 % coverage with `istanbul`. Here's the core setup:

model.js

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let PasteSchema = new Schema(
  {
    message: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: [String],
    marked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: Date
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('paste', PasteSchema);
```

controller.js

```
let Paste = require('./model');

// Other stuff

// I use a bit non-standard DELETE /pastes/:id for this
const markPaste = (req, res) => {
  Paste.findById({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, paste) => {
    if (!paste) {
      res.status(404).json({ result: 'Paste not found' });
      return;
    }
    paste.marked = true;
    paste.updatedAt = new Date();
    paste.save((err) => {
      err
        ? res.status(400).json({ result: err })
        : res.json({ result: 'Paste marked' });
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  markPaste,
  // Other stuff
}
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const pastes = require('./apps/pastes/controller'); // The file above

app.route('/pastes/:id')
  .delete(pastes.markPaste);

module.exports = app;
```

In the below test, I want to simulate an error being thrown in the `paste.save((err) => {` above.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Paste = require('../apps/pastes/model');
let server = require('../index');

let chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-http'));
chai.use(require('chai-date-string'));
let expect = chai.expect;
let sinon = require('sinon');
let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
let pastes = require('../apps/pastes/controller');
let httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');

// Other tests
```

Then the test I want to test `save()` error in the route:

```
it('should handle an error during the save in the endpoint', (done) => {
  // Create a paste to be deleted
  const pasteItem = new Paste({ message: 'Test 1', tags: ['integration', 'test'] });
  pasteItem.save()
    .then((paste) => {
      // Attempt code from below goes here
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Should not go here');
    });
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really find any clear reference to this in various Stack questions, or online, so here's how I did it:

The secret is in using the `sinon` sandbox, which applies even inside the route context during tests. Here is the working test:

```
it('should handle an error during the save in the endpoint', (done) => {
  const pasteItem = new Paste({ message: 'Test 1', tags: ['integration', 'test'] });
  pasteItem.save()
    .then((paste) => {
      // the sandbox is defined in the imports
      // This forces calling save() to raise an error
      sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model.prototype, 'save').yields({ error: 'MongoError' });
      chai.request(server)
        .delete('/pastes/' + paste._id)
        .end((err, res) => {
          // It applies within the route handling, so we get the expected 400
          expect(res).to.have.status(400);
          done();
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Should not go here');
    });
});
```

If you would call it outside of the sandbox, you would break all subsequent tests that use `sinon`. Ie.

```
// This would break things unintendedly
sinon.stub(mongoose.Model.prototype, 'save').yields({ error: 'MongoError' });

// This only breaks things (on purpose) in the test we want it to break in:
sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model.prototype, 'save').yields({ error: 'MongoError' });
```

If you have multiple things within the particular `sandbox` instance, you can of course restore the "unbroken" state within the test with `sandbox.restore();` after the test case.

->

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 60/60 )
Branches     : 100% ( 14/14 )
Functions    : 100% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : 100% ( 57/57 )
================================================================================
```

Yay!